# #LinkedIn How to get App to get r_1st_connections permissions

Tags: linkedin-api

We need use Connection Api,but don't have r_1st_connections permission in our App when we created.Only have these [Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNusv.png).And how we can get App to get r_1st_connections permission?

Answer (score 2):

To access `r_1st_connections` permissions, you have to create an app - https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps and select "Marketing Developer Platform" product. It covers access to `r_1st_connections` endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem than you. LinkedIn Staff inform that: *"Pleas note that the Connections API lives under our Compliance API program, which is a paid program that is not currently accepting additional partners. Both permissions (r_fullprofile or/and r_1st_connections) required to access calls for the Connections API live under this API program, so it is correct and expected that you would not be able to make calls against this endpoint at this time."* Regards

Comment: Thank you, but we still haven't found a way to become a LinkedIn partner.If you have a contact with LinkedIn staff, could you please share it with us?

Comment: Can you post a link to that statement please?